# javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find slider target component 'txt6; txt7' in view

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I tried the following example from [PrimeFaces `<p:slider>` showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/slider.jsf):

```
<h3>Range Slider</h3>  

<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px">                      
    <h:outputText id="displayRange" value="Between #{sliderBean.number6} and #{sliderBean.number7}"/>                      
    <p:slider for="txt6,txt7" display="displayRange" style="width:400px" range="true"   
              displayTemplate="Between {min} and {max}"/> 
</h:panelGrid>  
<h:inputHidden id="txt6" value="#{sliderBean.number6}" />  
<h:inputHidden id="txt7" value="#{sliderBean.number7}" />
```

However, it throws the following exception during rendering:

> Error Rendering View[/pages/slides.xhtml]: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find slider target component 'txt6; txt7' in view

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: I have just tried your code, it work fine, what version of Primefaces you used ?

Comment: I have just tried with primefaces 3.4 and 3.4.1; you right, "for" attribute of <p:slider doesn't support more than one id. If you use for="txt6", it work fine. i checked with primefaces 3.5, it support like your code.

Comment: if i just put for="txt6" i have not more a slider, i can change only one value.

Comment: I tried, but it may be a bug of Primefaces's slider :)

Comment: It was fixed in Primefaces 3.5: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2417

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Primefaces's slider bug in your Primefaces version, it was fixed in Primefaces version 3.5

You can see: [List Primefaces's bug](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list?can=1&q=label=TargetVersion-3.5%20status%3aFixed&sort=&groupby=&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Summary&nobtn=Update&num=500)
and [Release notes](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2417)